# Split domains in different sub menus in symfony sonata admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, menu, admin, sonata

Hy,

I'm working with Symfony '2.7' / [Sonata Admin 'dev-master'](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle)/ [IbrowsSonataTranslationBundle '2.7'](https://github.com/ibrows/IbrowsSonataTranslationBundle)

Here is my code in sonata_admin.yml :

```
 sonata.admin.group.administration:
            label:           sonata_administration
            label_catalogue: SonataAdminBundle
            icon:            '<i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>'
            items:
                - sonata.user.admin.user
                - sonata.user.admin.group
                #- sonata.page.admin.site
                # - sonata.notification.admin.message
                - ibrows_sonata_translation.admin.orm
```

So my problème is that i need to separate domains in different submenus if it's possible, does anyone know how to go through this.

I have three domains : messages, routes, system

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the answer that you are looking for.

in your ***src/AppBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml*** are the entities listed that you can edit in the Sonata adminBundle. under tags look for **group:** and change the value after **group:**